# Convert numbers (up to 4 digit) into words using switch statement ( C program)

Tags: c, type-conversion, switch-statement, digits

Switch statements
Converting  numbers to words
(3221) = Three thousand two hundred twenty one.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a place for programming Q&A, not a place where you can give a program description and ask for code (i.e. not a "free coding service").

Comment: Please add the code (your own) that you have already tried. Visit SO Help Center & look at the section on 'Asking' for more guidelines, including how to produce a 'Minimal Reproducible Example' >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

This C program prints numbers in word format for the range of 0 to 9999. Just send the number as a string for an argument in the `convert_to_words()` function in `main()`, and the program will compute the length of the number and use subsequent arrays to format the word based on the ones, tenths, hundredths, and thousandths positions. Keep in mind the conditional/decision structures used in this program are `if-else` statements instead of `switch-case`; if you want to edit it to use `switch-case` it would be relatively simple.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

/* A function that prints given number in words */
void convert_to_words(char *num) 
{ 
    int len = strlen(num); // Get number of digits in given number 

    /* Base cases */
    if (len == 0) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "empty string\n"); 
        return; 
    } 
    if (len > 4) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "Length more than 4 is not supported\n"); 
        return; 
    } 

    /* The first string is not used, it is to make 
        array indexing simple */
    char *single_digits[] = { "zero", "one", "two",  
                           "three", "four","five",  
                           "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"}; 

    /* The first string is not used, it is to make  
        array indexing simple */
    char *two_digits[] = {"", "ten", "eleven", "twelve",  
                           "thirteen", "fourteen", 
                           "fifteen", "sixteen",  
                           "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"}; 

    /* The first two string are not used, they are to make  
        array indexing simple */
    char *tens_multiple[] = {"", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", 
                        "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"}; 

    char *tens_power[] = {"hundred", "thousand"}; 

    /* Used for debugging purpose only */
    printf("\n%s: ", num); 

    /* For single digit number */
    if (len == 1) { 
        printf("%s\n", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
        return; 
    } 

    /* Iterate while num is not '\0' */
    while (*num != '\0') { 

        /* Code path for first 2 digits */
        if (len >= 3) { 
            if (*num -'0' != 0) { 
                printf("%s ", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
                printf("%s ", tens_power[len-3]); // here len can be 3 or 4 
            } 
            --len; 
        } 

        /* Code path for last 2 digits */
        else { 
            /* Need to explicitly handle 10-19. Sum of the two digits is 
            used as index of "two_digits" array of strings */
            if (*num == '1') { 
                int sum = *num - '0' + *(num + 1)- '0'; 
                printf("%s\n", two_digits[sum]); 
                return; 
            } 

            /* Need to explicitely handle 20 */
            else if (*num == '2' && *(num + 1) == '0') { 
                printf("twenty\n"); 
                return; 
            } 

            /* Rest of the two digit numbers i.e., 21 to 99 */
            else { 
                int i = *num - '0'; 
                printf("%s ", i? tens_multiple[i]: ""); 
                ++num; 
                if (*num != '0') 
                    printf("%s ", single_digits[*num - '0']); 
            } 
        } 
        ++num; 
    } 
} 

/* Driver program to test above function */
int main(void) 
{ 
    convert_to_words("9923"); 
    convert_to_words("523"); 
    convert_to_words("89"); 
    convert_to_words("8989"); 

    return 0; 
}
```

**Output:**

```
9923: nine thousand nine hundred twenty three
523: five hundred twenty three
89: eighty nine
8989: eight thousand nine hundred eighty nine
```